# "remoteContext object has no attribute"

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm running Spark 1.4 in Databrick's Cloud.  I loaded a file into my S3 instance and mounted it.  Mounting worked.  But I'm having trouble creating an RDD:
[image]
[image]

```
dbutils.fs.mount("s3n://%s:%s@%s" % (ACCESS_KEY, SECRET_KEY, AWS_BUCKET_NAME), "/mnt/%s" % MOUNT_NAME)
```

Any ideas?

```
sc.parallelize([1,2,3])
rdd = sc.textFiles("/mnt/GDELT_2014_EVENTS/GDELT_2014.csv")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've done a great job getting your data mounted into dbfs which is great, and it looks like you just have a small typo. I suspect you want to use `sc.textFile` rather than `sc.textFiles`. Best of luck with your adventures with Spark.